# Scale and Rotation Issue with Model Import 3DS Max to Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3dsmax, 3ds

I have just designed simple 3d model in 3ds Max and try to import within Unity. But notice one thing that is irrelevant for me, I was getting -90 rotation in X degree and scale of model is also not proper.

I don't know what is the reason behind this though I am beginner with 3ds max software.

[image]

As per above image, I hope you understand my point so what kind of settings, I require to do in 3ds max software so that it get imported with 0 rotation in X degree and with (1,1,1) scale.

Give me some suggestions into this.

Answer (score 1):

I have used this plugin for Blender and it works great for me:

[Unity Rotation Fix for Blender](https://forum.unity.com/threads/blender-unity-rotation-fix.181870/)

If you can't find a plugin for 3DS Max you can try to write similar plugin yourself or export your model to Blender and then use the plugin.

Here is the original Python code in case the link gets deprecated:

```
import bpy

bl_info = {
 "name": "Unity Tools",
 "author": "Karol \"Mirgar\" Głażewski",
 "version": (1, 0, 2),
 "blender": (2, 6, 5),
 "location": "3D View > Tool Shelf > Unity Tools",
 "description": "Tools to ease workflow with Unity Engine",
 "warning": "",
 "wiki_url": "",
 "tracker_url": "",
 "category": "Object"}

# fixes rotation on X axis, +X is -X in Unity compared to Blender
class UnityRotationFixerX(bpy.types.Operator):

    bl_description = "Fixes rotation of object so it will not \"lay on its face\" in Unity, +X axis is -X compared to Unity"
    bl_label = "Simple rotation fix"
    bl_idname = "object.unity_rotation_fix_x"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}


    def FixRotationForUnity3D(self):
        bpy.ops.object.transform_apply(rotation = True)
        bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value = -1.5708, axis = (1, 0, 0), constraint_axis = (True, False, False), constraint_orientation = 'GLOBAL')

        bpy.ops.object.transform_apply(rotation = True)
        bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value = 1.5708, axis = (1, 0, 0), constraint_axis = (True, False, False), constraint_orientation = 'GLOBAL')

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.mode == 'OBJECT' and context.area.type == 'VIEW_3D'

    def execute(self, context):
        self.FixRotationForUnity3D()
        return {'FINISHED'}

# fixes rotation on X and Z axis, front is now +Y
class UnityRotationFixerXZ(bpy.types.Operator):

    bl_description = "Fixes rotation of object, +Y is now front"
    bl_label = "Full rotation fix"
    bl_idname = "object.unity_rotation_fix_xz"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    def FixRotationForUnity3D(self):
        bpy.ops.object.transform_apply(rotation = True)

        bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value = -1.5708, axis = (1, 0, 0), constraint_axis = (True, False, False), constraint_orientation = 'GLOBAL')
        bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value = -3.1416, axis = (0, 1, 0), constraint_axis = (False, True, False), constraint_orientation = 'GLOBAL')

        bpy.ops.object.transform_apply(rotation = True)

        bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value = 1.5708, axis = (1, 0, 0), constraint_axis = (True, False, False), constraint_orientation = 'GLOBAL')
        bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value = 3.1416, axis = (0, 0, 1), constraint_axis = (False, False, True), constraint_orientation = 'GLOBAL')
    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.mode == 'OBJECT' and context.area.type == 'VIEW_3D'

    def execute(self, context):
        self.FixRotationForUnity3D()
        return {'FINISHED'}

class UnityPanel(bpy.types.Panel):

    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_unity_tools"
    bl_label = "Unity Tools"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'TOOLS'
    bl_context = "objectmode"
    bl_options = {'DEFAULT_CLOSED'}

    def draw(self, context):

        layout = self.layout

        col = layout.column(align=True)
        col.label(text="Rotation:")
        col.operator("object.unity_rotation_fix_x")
        col.operator("object.unity_rotation_fix_xz")


#registers    

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(UnityRotationFixerX)
    bpy.utils.register_class(UnityRotationFixerXZ)
    bpy.utils.register_class(UnityPanel)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(UnityRotationFixerX)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(UnityRotationFixerXZ)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(UnityPanel)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

And the installation guide:

> To install this addon unpack it to your Blender addon folder, e.g.
>   "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.67\scripts\addons" or
>   use install from file button in user preferences under addons tab.
>
> After installing, addon is in Object category and after enabling it,
>   can be accessed from Tool Shelf under "Unity Tools" panel.
>
> Note that complete rotation fix on X and Z axis will swap object so it
>   will face +Y axis instead -Y, if you export through fbx remember to
>   set Forward Z and Up Y as export axis when you use full rotation fix.

Answer (score 0):

Unity have different axis that 3D Max (and Blender etc.) and to fix that Unity is rotating models by default. Just Unity thing. If it's bordering you, you can always set your model as a child of an empty object.

Comment: Okay thanks for your reply but what I require to do within 3ds max? so that model get imported properly within Unity - I am more interested in that side solution so that programming way not get affected by this.

Comment: You can rotate it in 3D Max. But that's overkill, you should probably leave it like it is. That's official solution from Unity

Answer (score 0):

load the ball in 3d max, rotate it -90 degrees on the x axis, reset transform and re-export. as for the scale,

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/FBXImporter-Model.html

select the model in the inspector and check out its properties, specifically the import props.... do a little math and adjust the import scale.